# Execute a specific script file at reload of the page in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i want to reload curent tab for example at every 10 seconds, and then at each reload run a specific script which click on links on that tab:
i try this code in the background js file:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(test, 10000);

function test()
{
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.reload();
  });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file:"scriptInjection.js"
  });

}
```

and in the manifest.json file i set this permissions:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "browsingData", "notifications", "webRequest", "webNavigation", "http://*/", "https://*/" ]
```

the problem is when reload occur, click on links in that tab in the scriptInjection.js file don't occur.

Comment: Add a function callback to chrome.tabs.reload and move executeScript inside.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i do this and problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by adding a callback function to chrom.tabs.reload and run execute script in the callback function, now i have another question is it possible to use setTimeout for a function in scriptInjection.js file? i use setTimeout but it dosen't work and another qusetion, is it possible to use an other excute script in a callback?